# How to update docker container automatically on code changes

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

When I change code, the container doesn't automatically update it. It updates only when I run the `docker-compose build` command.

How can I update the Docker container automatically on code changes, without manually running `docker-compose build`?

Docker-compose file:

```txt
version: '3.8'
    
services:
    
  backend:
    build: .
    image: app:backend
    container_name: backend
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    restart: always  
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Docker file:

```txt
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

Comment: Can you use a non-Docker Python virtual environment, maybe with a tool like Pipenv to manage it?  What benefit do you get from using Docker in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using binded volume, try this:

```
version: '3.8'
    
services:
    
  backend:
    build: .
    image: app:backend
    container_name: backend
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    restart: always  
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - type: bind
      - source: .
      - target: app
```

With this way, when your container is running and you changed any code, it will reflect to container and program will restart.

Comment: Here's also https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/